# Populating a list with data from database using myBatis takes up a lot of time

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I have a table with almost 60000 data in it and I am running a select statement using myBatis mapper files, after analysing the code in debug mode I found that the data from the database was coming into DataSource fairly quickly, it was taking time while storing it in the List.

Driver Code.

```
Map<Long, Some_Custom_Class> mp = new HashMap<>();
List<Some_Custom_Class> myVar = selectAllDataFromTable();
if(myVar != null){
 for(Some_Custom_Class cs: myVar){
    mp.put(cs.getId(), cs)
 }
}
```

Mapper File

```
<select id="selectAllDataFromTable" resultMap="VariableMap">
   select  * from myTable
</select>

<resultMap id="VariableMap" type="myPackage.Some_Custom_Class">
        <id property="VariableID" column="variable_id" />
        <id property="SecondID" column="Second_ID" />
        <id property="Tag" column="tag" />
</resultMap>
```

I need to speed up the data insertion process in the list, is there any way to do it?
I know a way that but I am not sure if it is correct.
The way is by using threads and maybe having 2-4views and letting those threads access those views in some range let's say 0-10000 and so on. The for loop doesn't take much time to loop through 60000 data, but speeding that up will be a secondary task.
My goal is to populate the list in the fastest way possible, can someone help me with that.

Comment: Why should this be slow, do you maybe select some very large columns?

Comment: @Charles I would be glad if you can elaborate on very large columns, my Table contains 60000 entries and some column contains Text as well which contains description.

Comment: Try to select only the columns you really need. Don't use "select * from table"

Comment: @charles sure, but is there any other way to make it faster?

Comment: There is mapping going on and some reflection to map the database records to objects. If you only need performance then don't use an ORM. Use raw SQL and for example a simple JDBC ResultSet.